# Missing reference ExtendedDateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have inherited a VB project i need to finish.

Unfortunately i cant even rebuild because of a missing reference. I don't know where to find this **ExtendedDateTimePicker**

Is it a part of a non-standard assembly?

Comment: From what I read, `ExtendedDateTimePicker` is a class name which inherited `System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker` (there's no control found with `ExtendedDateTimePicker` name in `System.Windows.Forms` namespace). Possibly aforementioned class name included in a custom assembly.

Comment: Maybe one of these? [1](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/3579/extended-datetimepicker) | [2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17063/ExtendedDateTimePicker-control-with-week-numbers)

Comment: Check the project for DLL files which may include the control you are looking for. Add a reference to the DLL in your project. If there isn't one, then you'll have to examine the usage of the ExtendedDateTimePicker and see if either of MatSnow's links will fill the gap